# Protractor wait for all elements to have changed text

Tags: protractor

I want to wait till first element gets updated to rate same as monthlyRate variable and second element gets updated to rate same as annualRate.

With below code I get:

- Failed: Wait timed out after 9008ms

  ```
  public waitForSubscriptionRates = (rateselector: string, monthlyRate: string, annualRate: string) => {

  browser.wait(function(){
  element.all(by.css(rateselector)).filter(function(elem, index) {
      return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
          console.log('text=' + text);
          console.log('monthlyRate=' + monthlyRate);
          console.log('annualrate=' + annualRate);
          return (text === monthlyRate || text === annualRate);
      });
  }).first().click();
  },9000);
  ```

  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure do I understand your code well.

I assume that there are two selectors - first may contain text of `monthlyRate` and second `annualRate`. They can not be mixed, isn't it?

I don't get what you want to click.

Anyway, you can chain ExpectedConditions with `or` keyword.

See the example in the documentation: http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.or